# Specify wifi for auto connection

Tags: wireless

I have different wifi's available (lets call them 'wifi1' and 'wifi2'), when starting Ubuntu it always connects to 'wifi1'. Is it possible to set a configuration so it first tries to connect to 'wifi2' (and if not possible then to `wifi1')

Comment: Hi. Can you please mark your question as solved? This is helpful for other people to see how you solved your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a way around if someone got the same issue:
- Disable the autoconnect checkbox for 'wifi0' in EditConnections->wifi0->Edit->General